# Assert if there exist a td DOM with a specific text in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, assertion, testcafe

I just started using testcafe, so far I found the documentation helpful to do my test and automate my E2E.

I want to assert if a value exists in a td like this:

```
async checkBankAccount(accountNumber, currencyCode){
         const formatedAccount = formatBankAccount(accountNumber, currencyCode);
         console.log(formatedAccount);
         await t
         .expect(Selector('td').withText(formatedAccount).innerText).eql(formatBankAccount);
     }
```

I am having the following error:

> An assertion method is not specified.

I want to assert if it exists a td in my HTML that contains the text from formatedAccount.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the [exists](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists) property to check if an element is available.

```js
async checkBankAccount(accountNumber, currencyCode){
    const formatedAccount = formatBankAccount(accountNumber, currencyCode);
    console.log(formatedAccount);

    await t
         .expect(Selector('td').withText(formatedAccount).exists).ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to assert if your td contains the text coming from formatedAccount as follows:

```js
test ('test..', 
  async t => {
    const field = Selector('td'); 
    const text = field.textContent;


    await t
    .expect(text).contains(formatedAccount) 
});
```